# Exclude blank cells from SUMPRODUCT results?

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I learned of SUMPRODUCT through this forum yesterday and need some help understanding how to have it ignore blank cells when it's looking at numbers.  This is the formula I'm using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Export!DY:DY=A2)*(Export!IX:IZ<7))
```

The cells it's looking at could be blank or they could have a number between 0 and 10.  I'm trying to count the number of responses that are 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 6.  I've played with the formula a little and it seems that it's counting blanks and 0's as the same thing.  How can I tell it to ignore the blanks but count the 0's?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: to answer:  add `*(LEN(Export!IX:IZ)>0)` as a third.  But remember that this is an array type formula and using full column refs will cause issues if too many formulas are used.  Each formula will be doing over 7 million calcs that adds up quickly.

Comment: Thank you Scott.  As an aside, I tried to take your advice from yesterday and limit the number of rows for the calculations and was initially getting a #VALUE error when my formula looked like this.  

=SUMPRODUCT((Export!DY2:DY41201=A2)*((Export!IX:IZ=7)+(Export!IX:IZ=8)))

But I think I just figured out that I need to specify the columns in the other formulas as well.  Like this

=SUMPRODUCT((Export!DY2:DY41201=A2)*((Export!IX2:IZ41201=7)+(Export!IX2:IZ41201=8)))

Is that an accurate assessment?

Comment: yes they need to have the same number of rows.